# Can I substitute Maida Flour for All Purpose Flour for making Tortillas?

Tags: substitutions, indian-cuisine, mexican-cuisine

I'm attempting to make a Hot Cheeto Burrito. I've already subbed the Flaming Cheetos with a local substitute (Kurkure), and I'm going to make the Tortilla myself too. I have both Maida and Atta at hand.

I've seen answers that say it's an okay substitute if you're baking.

This is the recipe I'm going to use:

https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/157642/homemade-flour-tortillas/

https://tasty.co/recipe/hot-cheeto-burrito

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Maida and All purpose flour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14789/difference-between-maida-and-all-purpose-flour)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real tortilla would be made with corn flour or wheat flour. You can use the maida, it would taste little different, but not much to matter